# prove only one positive whole number solution (for every integer $y$)

Tags: collatz-conjecture

I have created an equation that might be able to solve half of the Collatz conjecture, but it requires a proof that is beyond me to make, and so I ask you.

for all positive integers of $y$

$$x = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{y-1} \left(3^i 2^{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{y-1-i} n_j\right)}\right)}{2^{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^y n_k\right)}-3^y}$$

$n_0=0$
$n_{\text{anything else}}=\text{new variable}$

I want someone to prove that for any positive integer $y$ there is only one positive integer solution $x$ where all other entries $(n_1,\space n_2,\space n_3, \cdots)$ are also positive integers.

Comment: How have you arrived at the equation. Mentioning that can provide insight to others if your solution provides any development to the actual conjecture.

Comment: @ChiefVS that, my friend, is a very lengthy explanation

Comment: @ChiefVS if you start with an odd number $x$ you can only do one thing in the Collatz conjecture $3x+1$, then you must divide divide by two, but you never know how many times, so $\frac{3x+1}{2^n}$ is what I came up with. then I realized that if any loop exists (of this type) then you could just set it equal to $x$ and find it (only solution possible was $1$ which made sense to me). then you start to iterate and solve,$x=\frac{3x+1}{2^{n_1}}$, $x=\frac{3\frac{3x+1}{2^{n_1}}+1}{2^{n_2}}$ and so on. the equation above is just a way to automatically solve said equations.

Comment: "**only solution possible was 1 that made sense to me**" isn't that the collartz conjecture, that everything leads to 1. (Also, I'm no expert in the field just a HS kid)

Comment: @ChiefVS yes, that's why there must be more than one solution (or that every solution is just$n_{\text{everything except 0}}=2$)

Comment: It is a well known formula for the test of the existence of a cycle (you can begin i.e. to read R. Crandall from 1978). Its nontrivial positive integer solution (except x=1) would indicate $x$ as member of such a nontrivial cycle. You won't find any one here who can ***prove*** the nonexistence of  integer solution $x>4$ ...

Comment: You might look at the discussion of this formula in my sketch http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf , see page 8 ff . Perhaps you find more interesting things in the essay, likely you'll find my notation for that formula and its friends better readable than yours.

Comment: A very similar question at mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344904/proof-that-3ns-sum-k-0n-1-3n-k-12a-k-2m

Answer (score 1):

### Notation

If you reformulate the collatz-transformation from one odd element $a_1$ to another odd element $a_2$ as such
$$  a_{k+1} = {3a_k+1\over2^{A_k}} \tag 1
$$
then the $N$-fold multiple consecutive transformation can be written as 
$$a_{N+1} = {3^N a_1+ 3^{N-1}2^{A_1} + 3^{N-2}\cdot 2^{A_1+A_2} + \cdots + 3^1\cdot 2^{A_1+A_2+...A_{N-2}} +2^{A_1+...+A_{N-1}} \over2^S} \tag 2
$$
where $N$ is the number of steps, and $S$ is the sum of the exponents.
Separating the fraction for easier handling and introducing the function $Q(E)$
$$a_{N+1} = {3^N \over 2^S} a_1+ { Q([A_1,A_2,...,A_N])  \over2^S} \tag 3
$$
where $Q(E)$ with the vectorial argument $E=[A_1,...A_N]$ is the long numerator *(which is also in the numerator of your sum)*:
$$ Q([A_1,A_2,....,A_N])= 3^{N-1}2^{A_1} + 3^{N-2}\cdot 2^{A_1+A_2} + \cdots + 3^1\cdot 2^{A_1+A_2+...A_{N-2}} +2^{A_1+...+A_{N-1}} \tag 4
$$
For completeness we define $Q([A])=1$ for any $A\ge 1$ if the arguments-vector has length $N=1$.

### Cycles

If we want a cycle, then this means that $a_{N+1}=a_1$ and eq (3) must take the form
$$a_1 = {3^N \over 2^S} a_1+ { Q([A_1,A_2,...,A_N])  \over2^S} \tag 5
$$
and we can rearrange
$$a_1\cdot 2^S-a_1\cdot 3^N =  Q([A_1,A_2,...,A_N])  \tag 6
$$
and finally arrive at the formula that you've given in your question:
$$ a_1= { Q([A_1,A_2,...,A_N])  \over 2^S-3^N} \tag 7
$$

### Simple solutions

Of course the trivial cycle has only one step and looks like
$$ 1= { Q([2])  \over 2^2-3^1} = { 1 \over 1}=1 \tag {8.1} $$
or repeated with two steps
$$ 1= { Q([2,2])  \over 2^4-3^2} = { 3 + 2^2 \over 7}=1 \tag {8.2} $$
or repeated with three steps
$$ 1= { Q([2,2,2])  \over 2^6-3^3} = { 3^2 +3\cdot 2^2 + 2^4 \over 37}=1 \tag {8.3} $$
and so on.
It is not so well known, that this gives quite immediately some solutions (=cycles) in negative integers:
$$ -1= { Q([1])  \over 2^1-3^1} = { 2^0  \over -1}=-1 \tag {9.1} $$
$$ -1= { Q([1,1])  \over 2^2-3^2} = { 3+2^1  \over -5}=-1 \tag {9.2} $$
$$ -1= { Q([1,1,1])  \over 2^3-3^3} = { 3^2+3\cdot 2^1 + 2^2  \over -19}=-1 \tag {9.3} $$
with the argument-vector $E=[1,1,1,....,1]$ of arbitrary length.
We even find the cycle
$$ -5= { Q([1,2])  \over 2^3-3^2} = { 3+2^1  \over -1}=-5 \tag {10.1} $$
of periodic argument-vector $E$ of arbitrary even length.
One more with $(N,S)=(7,11)$ :
$$ -17= { Q([1,1,1,2,1,1,4])  \over 2^{11}-3^7} = { Q(E)  \over -139}=-17 \tag {10.2} $$
with argument-vector $E$ which is periodic with period-length $7$.

### Open problem

However, nobody has succeeded to either ***find a (nontrivial) cycle*** or to ***prove the non-existence*** of the structure with $a_1 \gt 1$ being odd integer:
$$ a_1 = {Q(E)\over 2^S-3^N } \\
 \qquad \text{with } E=[A_1,A_2,...,A_N], A_k \ge 1 , \\
 \qquad S=\sum A_k ,\qquad 2^S \gt 3^N  \\
 \qquad a_1 \text{ is odd integer } \gt 1 \tag {11}
$$
In this formula we needed to find some combination of the $A_k$ which allows the result $a_1$ to be positive odd integer greater than $1$. There has been a lot of amateurish as well as professional discussion of this exponential diophantine equation and one can find online a big pile of coverage on this.

### Hints towards the problems in eq (11) from other examples

One of the problems for non-fractional divisibility in eq(11) is that the denominator should be small but the distance between perfect powers is generally large. There are few solutions known for the generalized problem $mx+1$ with $m=5$ and $m=181$ each for which the denominator is exceptionally small. In the following I generalize the $Q(E)$ -notation to the $Q_m(E)$-notation where the $m$ replaces the $3$ in eq.(1) and eq.(2) (making it an "$mx+1$-problem") and in the according $Q()$-definition.

- For $m=5$ we have $a_1=1 \to 3 \to 1 $ with $N=2$ and $S=5$ such that the formula 11 becomes
  $$ 1 = {Q_5([1,4])\over 2^5-5^2 } = {Q_5([1,4])\over 5 } \tag {12.1}
  $$
- For $m=5$ we have $a_1=13 \to ... \to 13 $ with $N=3$ and $S=7$ such that the formula 11 becomes
  $$ 13 = {Q_5([1,1,5])\over 2^7-5^2 } = {Q_5([1,1,5])\over 3 } \tag {12.2} $$
- For $m=5$ we have $a_1=17 \to ... \to 17 $ with $N=3$ and $S=7$ such that the formula 11 becomes
  $$ 17 = {Q_5([1,3,3])\over 2^7-5^2 } = {Q_5([1,3,3])\over 3 } \tag {12.3} $$
- For $m=181$ we have $a_1=27 \to ... \to 27 $ with $N=2$ and $S=15$ such that the formula 11 becomes
  $$ 27 = {Q_{181}([3,12])\over 2^{15}-181^2 } = {Q_{181}([3,12])\over 7 } \tag {12.4} $$
- For $m=181$ we have $a_1=35 \to ... \to 35 $ with $N=2$ and $S=15$ such that the formula 11 becomes
  $$ 35 = {Q_{181}([6,9])\over 2^{15}-181^2 } = {Q_5([6,9])\over 7 } \tag {12.5} $$

*(The two first cycles for $m=5$ and $m=181$ have been shown  already by R. Crandall in his 1978 article, but no more nontrivial cycles besides the $5$ cycles shown here are found from since until now (see wikipedia which would be aware of significant new results))*

"Exceptional" small denominators can be found using the convergents of the continued fraction of the transcendental values $\mu = \log_2(m)$ which for the case of $m=3$ has for instance "small" denominators for $N \in \{1,5,41,306,...\}$ which is fairly small for $N=5$  being $13$ but increases to $1909$ for $N=7$ and so on, and although $N=41$ has some "best" approximation the denominator becomes  $420491770248316829$ - which is not really "small" though...

---

***See also the question & discussion at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344904/proof-that-3ns-sum-k-0n-1-3n-k-12a-k-2m) in Nov 2019***